# Keep matchadd and matchaddpos up to date after file changes

Tags: vimscript, highlight

I'm trying to write a plugin to highlight overused words in a file. After [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8936/7642) I now have a way to highlight the most frequent words in each paragraph.

To restrict the highlighting of a word to a single paragraph I'm using `matchadd` with a line range:

```
matchadd('Error', word . '\%>' . (a:firstline - 1) . 'l\%<' . (a:lastline + 1) . 'l')
```

The problem is that if the user adds or removes a line in the middle of a file it messes up the highlighting of the following lines.

So how can I keep the highlighting up to date after changes in the file?

My first thought is to just clear the previous matches and highlight everything all over again when a line is added or removed. Is there no better way to do it? If there isn't, how can I detect if a line was added or removed so I can clear the matches and add them again?

Comment: You could keep track of the number of lines in the file. But I think a better approach is to reload the highlighting on an appropriate event, such as `InsertLeave`. The reloading should first clear all existing highlighting, which can be done with `matchdelete()`.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg Yes, but then the highlighting will be all wrong while the user is typing, especially if he types a lot all at once. I guess the more conservative approach would be to clear the highlighting  on `InsertEnter` and add it back on `InsertLeave`. But now that I'm looking into it I figured I can check if the number of lines is different on `CursorMovedI` and update if it is… or even update every time the user types a space to have "real time" highlighting, it doesn't seem to add too much overhead, I'm not sure if it would be considered bad practice. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could also use the `CursorMovedI`. However, as you've noticed, you should make sure to test this well, as it may have a large performance impact. If it is only for personal use, I wouldn't be too worried, but if you are working on a public thing, I would be more conservative.

Comment: I do hope more people will use the plugin. I'll leave it up to the user, then… "if you want to highlight matches, add this `autocmd`". Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue in my plugin, 
[diffchar.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4932).
This plugin highlights the exact diff units with matchadd/matchaddpos
and tries to interactively update those highlights while editing.

My approach is:

- always record which lines are highlighted
- get TextChanged/TextChangedI events
- get the post-edit contents of highlighted lines
- do 'undo'
- get the pre-edit contents of highlighted lines
- do 'redo'
- compare between pre and post to find which lines are changed
- clear highlights of changed line and then draw them

Since I do not think it is perfect, I am still looking for a better approach :-).

Comment: Wow, I was reading the `autocmd-events` documentation online instead of in ViM and it must have been an old version or something, because `TextChanged` wasn't mentioned. That'll be a huge improvement already!

Answer (score 0):

After looking into `:h autocmd-events` for a bit I came up with this:

```
let s:lastline = 0

function! MyAutoFunction()
    if line('$') != s:lastline
        " Clear previous matches
        " Add matches back
        let s:lastline = line('$')
    endif
endfunction

au TextChanged,TextChangedI * call MyAutoFunction()
```

And it seems to work pretty well.

If anybody has a better idea, I'm all ears. :)

---